# Ensuring that google analytics event sent before going to the next page

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

In a non-SinglePageApp, when you click on an anchor link to another page, the javascript will cancel and the new page will load.

This is a problem when I try to make asynchronous calls to google analytics attached to these anchor tags.

e.g., If I have a continue link and I want a ga event to trigger when it is clicked, if I add the event naively, it would get queued to load asynchronously but would sometimes not be called because browser will cancel the javascript and goto the next page before the ga 'continue clicked' event is processed.

I noticed GA has this attribute called 'hitCallback' and I tried to use that but it seems that I'm still not getting the continue event to process. I did it as thus trying to follow GA's guidelines here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/sending-hits#handling_timeouts

```
$('a.js-ga-track-event').click(function(e) { // jquery attaching to a element
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = this.href;
    var linkClicked = false;

    var clickLink = function() {
        if (href && !linkClicked) {
            linkClicked = true;
            window.location.href = href;
        }
    };

    // As a backup, will submit the form if GA does not succeed within 0.5 seconds
    setTimeout(clickLink, 500);

    var name = 'continue clicked';
    var label = '';
    ga('send', {
        'hitType': 'event',
        'eventCategory': 'EXAMPLE CATEGORY',
        'eventAction': 'continue clicked',
        'eventLabel': label,
        'hitCallback': clickLink
    });
});
```

The link is definitely not capturing all the event hits. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: One additional measure would be to set the "transport" field to "beacon", since that send the data even when the page unloads (browser support by now should be pretty good, and ga falls back to its default method when Navigator.sendBeacon(). is not supported).

Answer (score 1):

The `hitCallBack` is indeed what you want to use. The overall code logic looks good, however, I see that:

- The GA function name is uppercase (`GA` instead of `ga` as it should be)
- The syntax of the `send` call deviates from the [doc example](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/sending-hits#handling_timeouts)

Instead, why don't you try this:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'EXAMPLE CATEGORY', 'continue clicked', label, {
    hitCallback: clickLink
});
```

Comment: Hey @Max thanks for taking a look. I failed to add it but I actually import it as upper case in my real code. Will fix it though in the example. Also in the doc it looks like they have two ways of doing it. `ga('send', {
  hitType: 'event',
  eventCategory: 'Video',
  eventAction: 'play',
  eventLabel: 'cats.mp4'
});` is there if you scroll up. However, maybe I'll try doing it this other way and see if it makes a difference

Answer (score 1):

Set the transport field to 'beacon'. Easy as that.

Comment: sadly I have to support IE 11 and beacon is not supported on it :(  https://caniuse.com/#feat=beacon

Comment: @ThinkBonobo use a breakpoint beforeunload and wait for the google server to return 200